# Why INSERT creates X lock

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions, locking

We have simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    c1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    c2 INT,
PRIMARY KEY (c1)
) 
ENGINE=INNODB
```

1st transaction:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
start transaction;
insert into t1 set c2 = 1;
```

For some reason INSERT creates IX lock on t1 table. I expected no locks. Especially i did not expect only IX lock, without X lock on some row.

2nd transaction:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
start transaction;
update t1 set c2 = 2 where c1 = 1;
```

Here UPDATE statement creates IX lock on table t1 and create X lock on updated row. As i expected in read uncommited isolation level. But this X lock is waiting for X lock that belongs to 1st transaction. Yes, somehow it appears right now.

1. Why INSERT statement creates X lock on inserted row? What purpose? Where can i get information about such behaviour?
2. Why it happened in such weird way? Why INSERT created only IX lock and X lock appeared later?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behaviour for any database to lock in exclusive mode (X) any row or page it modifies. Also, READ UNCOMMITTED referrers to SELECT, nothing to do with INSERT.
To release the lock either COMMIT or ROLLBACK the first transaction.